# How can I stub the action_name in rails rspec.

Tags: rspec

In my view I have the following code

```
<h2><%= action_name.capitalize %> User</h2>
```

In my test I have the following

```
RSpec.describe 'users/new.html.erb', type: :view do

it 'displays the form to create a new user' do
assign :user, build(:user)

render

expect(rendered).to match 'Upload Image'
end
end
```

When I run the code I am getting the following

```
undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I stub the action_name variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check it myself now but according to [this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-7/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method) you can try this code

```
view.stub(:action_name).and_return("my_action_name")
```

If you get warning like below.

```
Deprecation Warnings:

Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from /home/akbarbin/Documents/Office/projects/portfolio/spec/views/admin/waste_places/new.html.erb_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 4.86 seconds (files took 4.72 seconds to load)
```

You can change it into

```
allow(view).to receive(:action_name).and_return("my_action_name")
```